# Текст лицензии на русском

Tags: opensource, лицензирование

У меня есть библиотека с открытым исходным кодом. Можно ли указать текст лицензии на русском языке, а не на английском?

Answer (score 2):

в принципе, ничто не мешает приложить к проекту лицензию хоть, например, на [ложбане](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD).

но в таком случае возникает справедливый вопрос: а с какой целью вы публикуете исходные тексты своей программы (библиотеки)?

если цель (или одна из целей) — привлечь других разработчиков к улучшению программы, то имеет смысл облегчить им процедуру подключения к разработке, а значит, использовать в лицензии английский язык (как наиболее распространённый в сфере информационных технологий).